# converting a 3D numpy array to 2D array in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I know this question has been asked before but it is not doing what I want it to. I have a 3D array of shape (66183,59,5) and I want to change it (66183,59*5). For example an array:

```
array([[[ 1.,  5.,  4.],
    [ 1.,  5.,  4.],
    [ 1.,  2.,  4.]],

   [[ 3.,  6.,  4.],
    [ 6.,  6.,  4.],
    [ 6.,  6.,  4.]]])
```

I want to convert it to 2D such that it looks like as follows:

```
array([[1,5,4,1,5,4,1,2,4],
   [3,6,4,6,6,4,6,6,4]])
```

How can I achieve this? Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.array.reshape`, and you need to pass the tuple of required shape.

Given array `arr`:

```py
arr.reshape((2,9))

array([[1., 5., 4., 1., 5., 4., 1., 2., 4.],
       [3., 6., 4., 6., 6., 4., 6., 6., 4.]])
```

For array `arr` with shape `((66183,59,5))`, you can reshape it into `(66183,59*5)` using `arr.reshape((66183,295))`